# JDA. GuildMemberJoin/LeaveEvent

Tags: java, bots, discord-jda

**I have written the following methods and they both are not working. Anyone know why and how to fix it?**

PS: The bot has admin perms.

```java
public class GuildMemberJoin extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        EmbedBuilder join = new EmbedBuilder();

        join.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(227, 74, 64));
        join.setTitle("SERVER UPDATE");
        join.setDescription(event.getMember().getAsMention() + " has now joined The server!");
        event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel().sendMessage(join.build()).queue();
    }
```

```java
public class GuildMemberLeave extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMemberLeave(GuildMemberLeaveEvent event) {
        EmbedBuilder join = new EmbedBuilder();
        TextChannel spamChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("713429117546135572");

        join.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(227, 74, 64));
        join.setTitle("SERVER UPDATE");
        join.setDescription(event.getMember().getAsMention() + " has now left the server!");
        spamChannel.sendMessage(join.build()).queue();
    }
```

**Default channel settings**

[image: channel settings]

Comment: What version of JDA are you using?

Comment: Did you register your adapter?  Did you include an `@Override` annotation? Did you verify that the events are even firing (e.i. did you add a `System.out.println("onGuildMemberJoin event fired")` and `System.out.println("onGuildMemberLeave event fired")` )?

Comment: I am using the latest JDA version. @Minn

Comment: @BroIamBro "latest" is not a valid version you have to be more specific

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica I will try the "`SOUT`" stuff now and see if anything happens. I didn't use @Override (if I have to use it. may u tell me where?). Yes I did register them ^

Comment: `@Override` is a code-validation which will make the compilation fail when your method signature does not properly override a method from the superclass

Comment: @Minn does this help? I use Gradle ^^

 ```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_154'
}
```

Comment: @BroIamBro that is definitely not latest in any form. The latest development version is **4.1.1_160** and the latest stable version is **4.1.1_101** but that means you are using a deprecated event.

Comment: @BroIamBro `@Override` should be directly above the `onGuildMemberJoin` method and the `onGuildMemberLeave` method.

Comment: @Minn oh, sorry about me saying latest at the beginning then ^
@Cardinal-ReinstateMonica I have just done that + added the `SOUT` things that u told me to do. no results.

Comment: That means your event is not event firing. Show us the code where you register it.

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica here's my main code.https://pastebin.com/b4NFqmWx
if u like the full code of everything, take a look at the comments under Minn answer that he just posted ^

Comment: I can't think of anything else. Try `JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build().awaitReady()`, and change `implementation 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_154'` to `implementation 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_160'`.

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica still does not work. Ima try Minn solution now (he just updated his answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the [JDA Wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed):

> There are many reasons why your event listener might not be executed but here are the most common issues:
>
> 1. You are using the wrong login token?
>
>    If the token is for another bot which doesn't have access to the desired guilds then the event listener code cannot run.
> 2. Your bot is not actually in the guild?
>
>    Make sure your bot is online and has access to the resource you are trying to interact with.
> 3. You never registered your listener?
>
>    Use `jda.addEventListener(new MyListener())` on either the `JDABuilder` or `JDA` instance
> 4. You did not override the correct method?
>
>    Use `@Override` and see if it fails. Your method has to use the correct name and parameter list defined in `ListenerAdapter`.
> 5. You don't actually extend `EventListener` or `ListenerAdapter`.
>
>    Your class should **either** use `extends ListenerAdapter` or `implements EventListener`.
> 6. You are missing a required `GatewayIntent` for this event.
>
>    Make sure that you `enableIntents(...)` on the `JDABuilder` to allow the events to be received.
> 7. The event has other requirements that might not be satisfied such as the cache not being enabled.
>
>    Please check the requirements on the event documentation.
>
> If none of the above apply to you then you might have an issue in your listener's code, at that point you should use a debugger.

For clarification:

You can enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent by doing `builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)` on `JDABuilder`.

For example:

```java
JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);
builder.addEventListeners(myListener);
JDA jda = builder.build();
```

See also: [Gateway Intents and Member Cache Policy](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy)

Comment: I (believe that I) have done all the following stuff that u listed except for number 6 cuz I am not sure how to do that (I am kinda new to jda) anyways here are my full codes https://gyazo.com/fadc0f4bed9d4cc5901d113379576907 https://gyazo.com/508908e35c7c49658060bab97d23be07