# Why does GuildMemberJoinEvent for Discord JDA not work?

Tags: java, discord

I'm trying to code a discord bot with Java and, for some reason, GuildMemberJoinEvent is not working. Other events such as MessageRecievedEvent are working.

Here is how I listen for GuildMemberJoinEvent:

```java
public class Joins extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Member Joined");
    }
}
```

I register it to the JDABuilder like this:

```java
Joins joins = new Joins();
jdaBuilder.addEventListeners(joins);
```

Other events, such as MessaveReceivedEvent, work just fine. I used the exact same method to listen for them and register them in my main class. How would it be possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Does your bot have the require privileges

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDA. GuildMemberJoin/LeaveEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267453/jda-guildmemberjoin-leaveevent)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267453/jda-guildmemberjoin-leaveevent)

For your bot to get the required events, you need to enable the "Server members intent" on your bots application page in the discord developer portal.

[image: See this image]

Comment: I tried enabling both, but still it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the question in my answer

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you add the event listener after JDA has been built.

That's how it should be done - and also, as mentioned by MrCodingB, make sure the intent is enabled:

```
jdaBuilder.addEventListeners(new Joins());
JDA jda = jdaBuilder.build().awaitReady();
```